Can I change the coordinates of the problem to avoid dynamic mesh?
I am looking to simulate the velocity field of a fluid around a fish. Fortunately, some analytical functions have been derived for specific cases (e.g., A Generalized Slender-Body Theory for Fish-Like Forms, Newman 1973). Deriving these equations is quite challenging, but by applying calculus and carefully reading the paper, it is achievable.
I want to learn about CFD and plan to validate those equations with a CFD simulation. I intend to start with simpler cases from classical books and then proceed to more advanced cases like those in the paper.
From what I've seen, implementing a dynamic mesh seems to be the standard approach for this type of CFD problem, and I am prepared to do so if necessary. However, I've also considered an alternative approach: solving the partial differential equations representing the system’s dynamics by changing coordinates. This approach is used in the paper to switch to a reference frame fixed to the fish, effectively making the fish stationary.
$$X=x, \quad Y=y,\quad Z=z-h(x,t), \quad T=t.$$
My question is whether this is a feasible solution to avoid the complexity of a dynamic mesh. I was planning to use OpenFOAM for this, but I am open to any suggestions on how to implement the solver. If you have any advice on how to do this manually, I would appreciate it, as my goal is to deepen my understanding of the underlying concepts in CFD. Also, can this approach be applied to other geometries as well?

Isn't this what sets the "Arbitrary Lagrangian-Eulerian (ALE)" method apart from the Eulerian approach (mesh is fixed) and the Lagrangian approach (mesh moves with the velocity)?

Thank you very much for this information. This is exactly what I was searching for. As I said I'm learning the basics and it was a little bit odd not to find information about this kind of transformation.
